# Find multiple occurrences in string with Javascript

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is have something like this

```
string = 'I\'m a value with "quotes1" that could have other "quotes2" at the same time'
```

to have the locations of all ' " ' be found and put into an array.

The code that I currently have is malformed and was trying to use two variables to find two points to use `.slice()` on. Roughly this.

```
function quoteslice(com) {
    if (com.indexOf('"') !== -1) {
        slicepoint1 = com.indexOf('"');
        com = com.slice(0,slicepoint1 + 1);
        slicepoint2 = com.indexOf('"');
        com = com.slice(0, slicepoint2);
        return com;
    } else {
        return com;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement this yourself? It looks like you're just asking people to do the work for you. Where exactly are you having problems here?

Comment: Have you tried anything - say split http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Just found my own solution to what I need to do (use .split()), but that doesn't pertain what was asked in the first place so I'll keep this open for people attempting the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = 'I\'m a value with "quotes1" that could have other "quotes2" at the same time';
var res = [];
for(var i=0; i < str.length; i++) { 
  if(str[i]==='"') { res.push(i) } 
}
```

Escaped characters (\) are **not** counted

Comment: I've posted an answer with `indexOf()`.
I'm pretty sure that `indexOf()` is faster...

Comment: Tested this in Chrome's debug and I must warn future users of this code to note that escaped characters **are** not counted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var string = 'I\'m a value with "quotes1" that could have other "quotes2" at the same time';
var pos = 0;
var array = [];

while ((pos = string.indexOf("'", pos)) > -1) {
    array.push(++pos);
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to get the first quoted string in `str`, you can use a regular expression:

```
var quotedString = str.replace(/^[\s\S]*?('.*?')[\s\S]*$/, '$1');
```

Comment: Tried putting this into a debugger and the variable 'array' doesn't spit out any results

Comment: @WhiteFusion I've corrected it now.